# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc() and WC()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I just created a file called `custom_functions.php` inside of my current active child theme, and when I try to add a product to the cart with this simple line of code, I get an error:

Code:

```
<?php
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 204 );
    //wc()->cart->add_to_cart( 204 );
?>
```

Error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function WC() in /homepages/11/d870651981/htdocs/clickandbuilds/XXXXXXX/wp-content/themes/motors-child/custom_functions.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /homepages/11/d870651981/htdocs/clickandbuilds/XXXXXXX/wp-content/themes/motors-child/custom_functions.php on line 2
```

I have been reading on Internet that you don't need to import anything else, just use `WC()`.

I'm executing that code from `functions.php` file using `jQuery AJAX`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be clear, you are calling this file directly from AJAX? If so, this won't work because WordPress does not get "booted up" in that scenario, and you should look into [`wp_ajax_nopriv_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/) or [`wp_ajax_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/)